# visual studio 2008 , asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

Hello I was wondering how to get the starter template for asp.net mvc showing in vs2008

I currently have mvc installed , have been working with VS2010 but  need to create a separate project for VS2008. How can I get the MVC template showing up for VS2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Asp.Net MVC is built into Visual Studio 2010 it probably only creates the templates for VS 2010. If you install ASP.Net MVC for .Net 3.5 I imagine it will have the templates for VS 2008.

Here is the link for ASP.Net MVC 2 RTM for Visual Studio 2008:
[Download Link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

The templates aren't included by default with Visual Studio 2008 like they are with VS 2010. You can download and install them from one of these two links:

[Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/2.0/WebProductList.xml&appid=MVC2)

[Standard Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en)

Comment: Ok Ihave done that after having to install sp1 for VS2008, took ages. I still cant see the templates. This is now getting critical, as Im running out of time .

Comment: sorry my bad it is  there , I had to shut down my vs and restart Thanks a lot Guys.